# Jquery ui datepicker Internet Explorer document mode 5 or 8 breaks inline with numberOfMOnths matrix

Tags: jquery-ui, internet-explorer, jquery-ui-datepicker

Hello there i'm trying to use datepicker in the famous (never working right) Internet Explorer, and because of limitations the IE browser is set to document mode 8 by default. ( Don´t ask why is stupid i know ). Nevertheless i need to get the job done.

Jquery 1.7.1
Jquery UI 1.8.17

Problem: In IE11 Doc.8 or 10 Doc.8 this happens while navigating throught the months:

[image]

This is what i set the datepciker for:

```
$(element).datepicker({
          id: identifier,                 
          firstDay: 1,
          showOtherMonths: true,
          monthNamesShort:monthNamesShort,
          dayNamesShort:dayNamesShort,
          changeYear: true,
          yearRange: getCalendarsYearRange(0),
          //selectOtherMonths: true,
          changeYear: true,
          numberOfMonths: [2, 3],
          showButtonPanel: false,
          minDate: new Date(minDateMaxDate[0] * 1000),
          maxDate: new Date(minDateMaxDate[1] * 1000),
          inline: true
    });
```

Anyone has any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the problem by making months with short name instead off full, i guess this only happens on portuguese language or languages with full month names long.

```
monthNames:['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Abr', 'Mai', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Ago', 'Set', 'Out', 'Nov', 'Dez'],
```